# find unique values at a given position in a numpy array of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, tuples, unique

I have a numpy array that looks like this:

```
[
('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo1.jpg', []),
('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo2.jpg', []),
('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C63}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo1.jpg', []),
('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C73}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo1.jpg', [])
]
```

How can i find the unique values at "position 0" of each tuple? Ideally i'd like to output an array (or list) that looks like this:

```
[
'{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}',
'{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C63}',
'{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C73}'
]
```

Comment: What's the `dtype`?  If it displays as a list of tuples, it must be structured.  `arr['f0']` is the field named `f0'.  You should be able to apply `np.unique` to that array.

Comment: @hpaulj when i print the dtype of the np array, i get this `[('REL_GLOBALID', '<U38'), ('CONTENT_TYPE', '<U150'), ('ATT_NAME', '<U250'), ('DATA', 'V')]`.  when i do `np.unique(np_array['REL_GLOBALID'])`, i do get the array of unique values.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreating a structured array from your display:

```
In [241]: _ = np.array([
     ...: ('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo1.jpg', []),
     ...: ('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo2.jpg', []),
     ...: ('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C63}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo1.jpg', []),
     ...: ('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C73}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo1.jpg', [])
     ...: ],dtype='U50,U20,U20,O')
Out[241]: 
array([('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo1.jpg', list([])),
       ('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo2.jpg', list([])),
       ('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C63}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo1.jpg', list([])),
       ('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C73}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo1.jpg', list([]))],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U50'), ('f1', '<U20'), ('f2', '<U20'), ('f3', 'O')])
```

Selecting the first field:

```
In [242]: _['f0']
Out[242]: 
array(['{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}',
       '{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}',
       '{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C63}',
       '{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C73}'], dtype='<U50')
```

Applying `unique` to that:

```
In [243]: np.unique(_)
Out[243]: 
array(['{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}',
       '{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C63}',
       '{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C73}'], dtype='<U50')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use set() combined with list comprehension:

```
x = [
('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo1.jpg', []),
('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo2.jpg', []),
('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C63}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo1.jpg', []),
('{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C73}', 'image/jpeg', 'Photo1.jpg', [])
]
y = set(i[0] for i in x)
y
{'{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C63}',
 '{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C73}',
 '{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) after slicing first column (`[:, 0]`)

```
>>> np.unique(arr[:,0])

array(['{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C33}',
       '{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C63}',
       '{893EE51E-0CD1-4C06-B672-365EECA26C73}'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: when i execute your suggested command, i get the following error message. IndexError: too many indicies for array.   I am using python 3.6.2